# Detect closing of the 'print' action in a browser

Tags: jquery, browser, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting browser print event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234008/detecting-browser-print-event)

I am using jquery to move around some html (adding, deleting) so if a user prints the page it comes out nicer.

How can I target the print window prompt once its been closed so I can reverse it back to its original state?

#### My print button

```
<div id="printthispage" onClick="window.print();return false;"></div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using media queries for this so the layout changes automatically when printing?

Comment: Info about media queries in CSS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Yes, you are more corrector. But, in case JS needed to handle it, use the events.

Comment: I am using print.css file in conjunction with some jquery.

Answer (score 1):

There are some events that have been adopted since FF 6 and it is native in IE. I believe this works in chrome, too.

body.onafterprint and body.onbeforeprint

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Printing#Detecting_print_requests

Comment: What if the user cancels and doesn't print the page? would it still trigger?

Comment: ACtually, jfriend00 is correct. use media queries.

Comment: if you need it for js, yes, i believe cancelling would also trigger the event.