# jQuery hide/show don't play well with @media print

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a webpage that hides and shows various pieces using jQuery's `hide()` and `show()` functions in response to user actions.  If the user prints the page, I want all those pieces to be shown, and I've got an `@media print` section of my stylesheet to do that.  However, jQuery's functions override this.  How can I solve this problem?

Comment: why don't you temporarily `show()` them all just before printing?

Comment: @Nicholas, how do I hook Javascript into the browser's "print" menu option?  `window.onbeforeprint`, for example, isn't standardized or cross-browser.

Comment: err...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234008/detecting-browser-print-event ..Bu this is actually a hack. I would suggest, if you are at the early development stages to rethink if you really need to use `hide()` and `show()`. Maybe you should just abstract into a function the hide and show, and use your own CSS  class toggling - as described below - that plays well with `@media print`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**html**

```
<div class="pieces">hello world</div>
```

if use jQuery `hide();` it would output

```
<div class="pieces" style="display: none;">hello world</div>
```

style property declared and their priority over others here. so there has a solution, add a class `display:none;`

```
<style>
.hide{display:none;}

@media print{

    .hide{display:block;}
}
</style>
<div class="pieces hide">hello world</div>
```

use `$('.pieces').addClass('hide')` instead of `$('.pieces').hide()`

`$('.pieces').removeClass('hide')` instead of `$('.pieces').show()`

print demo http://jsfiddle.net/abj01sa7/3/show/