# Determine If Print/Cancel Button in Google Chrome's Print Preview is Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, printing-web-page

I've been printing my page using the code below:

```
window.print();
```

An image below is what the print preview in Google chrome browser looks like. It has two main buttons: `print` and `cancel`.

[image]

I want to know if the user has clicked the `print` or `cancel` buttons. What I did uses jquery:

HTML Code of the Print Preview:

```
<button class="print default" i18n-content="printButton">Print</button>
<button class="cancel" i18n-content="cancel">Cancel</button>
```

Jquery Code:

```
 $('button > .cancel').click(function (e) {                
      alert('Cancel');
 });

 $('button > .print').click(function (e) {                
      alert('Print');
 });
```

I tried the code above with no luck. What am I missing?

Comment: As a side comment, `button > .cancel` would have not selected the cancel button, but an element with `cancel` class inside a button. The right selector would have been `button.cancel` (but that won't work anyway)

Comment: I also wants know about cross browser solution is any

Comment: U want to find what??? the behind coding inside print?

Comment: @alyssaeliyah Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 22):

You can not access Chrome's internal windows (printing dialog in this case) directly from a regular web page.

```
    (function () {

        var beforePrint = function () {
            alert('Functionality to run before printing.');
        };

        var afterPrint = function () {
            alert('Functionality to run after printing');
        };

        if (window.matchMedia) {
            var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print');

            mediaQueryList.addListener(function (mql) {
                //alert($(mediaQueryList).html());
                if (mql.matches) {
                    beforePrint();
                } else {
                    afterPrint();
                }
            });
        }

        window.onbeforeprint = beforePrint;
        window.onafterprint = afterPrint;

    }());
```

Or, If you want to do something when the print preview gets opened, you can try below:

```
$(document).bind("keyup keydown", function (e) {
         if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 80) {
             setTimeout(function () { CallAfterWindowLoad();}, 5000);
             return true;
         }
     });

    function CallAfterWindowLoad()
    {
        alert("Open and call");
    }
```

Reference: 
[How to capture the click event on the default print menu called by Javascript window.print()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31970829/how-to-capture-the-click-event-on-the-default-print-menu-called-by-javascript-wi)

Maybe if you provide your requirements for this two buttons click event, we can provide you an alternate solution.

Comment: please give us the solution, I need to know if the user click the `print` button in order to print an invoice with ORIGINAL tag so later I put a flag in database and allowing to print only DUPLICATE, TRIPLICATE and so on..

Comment: @user12163165 that's simply not possible.

Answer (score 7):

it is very easily possible:

```
<body onafterprint="myFunction()">
```

The myFunction() that you can define within a  tag will be fire when either the printing job is done or the cancel button was pressed.

Comment: In the question he wanted to know which button is pressed `cancel` or `print`

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
            window.print();

            onafterprint = function () {
                window.location.href = "index.html";
            }
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the print preview is not part of any `document` your JS can access. These might interest you:

[Detecting browser print event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1234008/1630906)

[ExtJS 4 - detecting if the user pressed "Print" on the print dialog that was called programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28620711/1630906)

Answer (score 0):

Try this adjusted code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function wind()
    {
        
    document.getElementById('prin').style.display='none'; 
        window.print();
        window.addEventListener("click", function()
        {
            document.getElementById('prin').style.display='block';
        }
        );
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="prin" onclick="wind()">Print</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Inside the anonymous function write console.log('its working')';,so that you come to know user has clicked cancel/print in printing prompt

Answer (score -3):

This should do the trick. I've used jQuery v2.2.0 which is included in the html file.

```
$("#print").click(function() { // calls the id of the button that will print
    document.body.style.visibility = 'hidden'; //code for hiding the body
    document.getElementById('printthis').style.visibility = 'visible'; // div to be printed
    document.getElementById('printthis').style.position = 'absolute'; //some code/css for positioning. you can adjust this
    document.getElementById('printthis').style.top = '40px';
    document.getElementById('printthis').style.left = '0px';
    if (print()) { // shows print preview.

    } else { // else statement will check if cancel button is clicked.
        document.body.style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('printthis').style.position = '';
        document.getElementById('printthis').style.top = '';
        document.getElementById('printthis').style.left = '';
        alert("Print Canceled");
    }
});
```

I guess this might as well be used as a way to print certain divs in your html. Just hide the `body` element and only show the div that you want to print with some positioning css. Hope it works in yours. I've tried it and I can say that it worked for me.