# Determine which pages were printed

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-viewer

I am writing an application which can only allow users to print pages once. I am looking for a way to find out which pages have been sent to the printer to update a database to mark those pages are printed.

Comment: how are you invoking the print?

Comment: I am invoking it through the .PrintReport() function as i have disabled the print function in the viewer since i have to add code to remove the pages from being printed again

Answer (score 0):

You have to capture the printer button and store to your own control.

After that you can work with media print on your divs to display or not display the content when the printer button is clicked.

Take a look how to capture the button here: [How to capture the click event on the default print menu called by Javascript window.print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31970829/how-to-capture-the-click-event-on-the-default-print-menu-called-by-javascript-wi)

Comment: The application is windows based and not web based. Also, a preview of the report is to be given and therefore the crystal reports viewer was used. I am asking how to capture the print event for this an not for printing a web page which use different controls

Comment: You should be more specific on your question and tell your sceneario. I have no expertise on crystal reports. Gook Luck!