# How to change the database if printed?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a button that prints

```
<input type = "button" onclick = "printDiv ('printableArea')" class = "button1" value = "Print" />


<script>
    function printDiv (divName) {
        var printContents = document.getElementById (divName) .innerHTML;
        var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

        document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

        window.print ();

        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
    }
</script>
```

And it sends to print operation.

The customer currently has the option to print or cancel.

Is there a way to access code behind in case the customer presses a print button?
(I want to change in my database that the client has already printed ...)

Regards

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to access code behind in case the customer presses a print button?

Please note that we can not directly detect if user clicked the 'Print' or 'Cancel' button in printing dialog via JS code from a html page.

*Similar issue discussed in this SO thread: [How to capture the click event on the default print menu called by Javascript window.print()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31970829/how-to-capture-the-click-event-on-the-default-print-menu-called-by-javascript-wi)*

As a workaround, you can try to show a prompt dialog to confirm if the printing is complete and then make request to backend to update database once the [`afterprint` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onafterprint) is raised, like below.

```
window.onafterprint = function () {
    var message = "Have you printed the page(s)?";
    var result = window.prompt(message,"yes");
    if (result=="yes") {
        //...
        //make ajax request to backend 
        //...
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a GET request to an MVC Action like (in jQuery):

```js
...
document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

var clientId = $("#clientId").val();
$.get("@Url.Action("SavePrinted", "Client")", { clientId: clientId });

window.print();
...
```