# Wait for window.onbeforeprint to finish DOM manipulation before print preview

Tags: javascript, printing, event-handling, dom-events

According to the [official docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeprint) `window.onbeforeprint` *allow[s] pages to change their content before printing starts (perhaps to remove a banner, for example).*

However, this doesn’t work in my cases, since `window.onbeforeprint` is fired asynchronously — like any event in JS. I do change the DOM content in my event handler, but the changes are not in the print preview. Only, when I cancel the first print attempt and hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> again, the changes (of the first event) inside the DOM are part of the print preview.

I’m not talking about long-running processes here like fetching something from the net. Just simple copy/paste inside the DOM.

So I wonder if I’m doing anything wrong here, or if `window.onbeforeprint` is pretty much pointless for changing content prior to printing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some additional troubleshooting, I can confirm, that `window.onbeforeprint` actually allows DOM manipulations to happen before the print view is generated. The problem in my case was the framework: Vue.js. The Vue component didn’t update in time. If I manipulate the DOM directly inside the event handler, it works.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem like it's possible to abort the print using `onbeforeprint` either. (neither the event return value nor `e.preventDefault()` is respected)  (https://stackoverflow.com/a/28937612/1517969)

Comment: It's also unfortunate that the print styling seems to be applied *after* `onbeforeprint`.