# force delay before browser print

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, html-to-pdf

### TLDR

I want to increase the time available to manipulate the DOM before the print version is generated.

### Use case

In a website I work on, we have embedded charts from a 3rd party provider (Qlik).
We now want to be able to print the page with the charts using the browser's native print functionality.

The charts need to be redrawn in a different size before printing, otherwise they will look cut off.

The scripts from the 3rd party do subscribe to a resize event, which I can trigger using e.g. `window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));`. Or alternatively I can directly call `qlik.resize();`.

### Problem

On print, if I attempt to trigger a redraw on 'beforeprint', I see the redrawn charts only in the actual webpage, whereas the print preview still shows the old version of the charts before the redraw, or a broken half-redrawn version.

### Observations

It seems that starting with the 'beforeprint' event, I still have ~210 milliseconds to alter the DOM, after that further changes have no effect on the printed output.

I get to the 210ms with the following experiment:

```js
  // (This sample uses jQuery, adjust as you see fit)
  const $display = $('h2#chart-section');
  window.addEventListener('beforeprint', function () {
    console.log('beforeprint', window.matchMedia('print').matches);
    $display.append(' beforeprint');
    for (let dt = 0; dt < 1000; dt += 10) {
      window.setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('beforeprint t0', window.matchMedia('print').matches);
        $display.append(' t' + dt);
      }, dt);
    }
  });
```

The `h2` in the printed version will be like '...t210', whereas in the screen version it goes up to '...t990', even while the print preview is open.

Also interestingly the `window.matchMedia('print').matches` always gives `false`.

### Question

How can I force more time to pass before the print version is "frozen"?

Comment: Have you tried having a print button that opens a page that specifically is made for print and has the charts already drawn for print?

Comment: It's not possible to cancel the print https://stackoverflow.com/a/28937612/3807365 - so therefore probably not possible to delay it

Comment: I think, normally, you'd use `qlik.resize()`. However, the docs say that this just fires off resize events to each qlik component, which separates those actions from the `beforeprint` event. I think you need a way to resize without wrapping that action in new events. Also, this may not be resolvable if qlik requires retrieving remote content to do the resize, as in a SaaS.

Comment: @imvain2 Yes, the dedicated print button is an alternative solution I am following. However in this question I would like to see how far I can get with plain native browser print. In the end, if I choose the alternative, I want to be able to explain why browser print is a dead end.

Comment: @Ouroborus My experiment suggests that it would work if the new events all complete in under 200ms. But it seems that Qlik needs longer than that.

Comment: In my own testing, in Firefox, nothing in the `setTimeout` callbacks make it into the printed document. Just the " beforeprint" from the event callback.

Comment: @Ouroborus I confirm, Firefox gives me none. Chromium consistently gives me around ~210ms, even for a totally different test document.