# Show PDF for Website Printing

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing

Can you link printing a webpage to printing a PDF?

Ideally, the PDF would be downloaded once the user uses the browser's print functionality (so a performance hit doesn't affect users who are not printing the website).

I'm looking for a Javascript/CSS print media query solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

You can trigger Javascript to run on a print event, redirecting the user to a PDF (works for IE 5+, Firefox 6+, Chrome 9+, and Safari 5+):

[Detecting browser print event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234008/detecting-browser-print-event)

Replace the console.logs in the code snippet from the above link with window.location = "http://whatever.you.want.com"

Using this method, the print dialog will open briefly, close immediately and redirect the user to a PDF where they will have to hit the print button again.