# Detect Print Event on PDF in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, events, pdf, printing

I want to detect the print Event and used this code: [Detecting browser print event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234008/detecting-browser-print-event).

I works very fine for normal pages. But it does not work with following HTML-Code

```
<object type="application/pdf" width="100%">
</object>
```

Using the Print Button from the embedded Toolbar do not fire the print Event.

Any solutions for this problem?

Thanks you

Comment: seems to have a good documentation about print events: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Printing