# Method for telling if webpage inside iframe is attempting to print something

Tags: javascript, iframe

Hi I am embedding a webpage using iframe. The webpage consists of a form, which upon being submitted opens a pdf and print dialog for the screen. How can I use javascript to tell if the pdf is being printed?

For example, heres essentially what I want to do in pseudo code

```
if(document.getElementById('iframe').webpageisPrinting){
     //prevent webpage from printing
     //do other stuff
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting browser print event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234008/detecting-browser-print-event)

Comment: @George I don't believe these are the same questions/duplicates. That question does  ask about printing (it also appears that the accepted answer does not work for iframe [I tested it on my app] and some of the other responses do not work today), but does not ask about iframes. Can you please clarify on code that would work for iframe