# matchMedia().addListener marked as deprecated, addEventListener equivalent?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, matchmedia

I'm making use of `matchMedia().addListener` to detect dark/light mode theme preference changes in Safari, however in WebStorm using `addListener` is marked as deprecated but simply says to refer to documentation for what should replace it.

I've had a read through the MDN docs and I don't understand what event type I should be listening for in `addEventListener` to replace `addListener`?

```js
window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").addListener(() => this.checkNative());
window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: light)").addListener(() => this.checkNative());
```

Answer (score 136, accepted):

From the doc - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener

> A function or function reference representing the callback function you want to run when the media query status changes.

It should be `change` event. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/onchange.

```
const mql = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");

mql.addEventListener("change", () => {
    this.checkNative();
});
```

Comment: TypeError: window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").addEventListener is not a function.

Comment: What you get in `mql`?

Comment: It's a MediaQueryList as expected

Comment: @MattCowley - I do not have much idea about `matchMedia`, but the example provided in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/onchange `window.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)');` works perfectly.

Comment: Ah, looks like this isn't supported in Safari yet, yet addListener is. How odd...

Comment: Similar issue with iPhone 6s running IOS 13.4.1 - logs error addEventListener is not a function. Had to revert code to deprecated addListener() to get Angular web app to work on both Safari and Chrome on iPhone. Any ideas what changed?

Comment: FYI: at time of writing a patch has landed in WebKit to address this, just isn't in Safari yet: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203288

Comment: @MattCowley Not odd at all. Safari is terrible at following W3C standards.

Answer (score 66):

Chrome and Firefox handle it differently than Safari, I solved it with way:

```
const darkMediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');

  try {
    // Chrome & Firefox
    darkMediaQuery.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
      this.$vuetify.theme.dark = !this.$vuetify.theme.dark;
    });
  } catch (e1) {
    try {
      // Safari
      darkMediaQuery.addListener((e) => {
        this.$vuetify.theme.dark = !this.$vuetify.theme.dark;
      });
    } catch (e2) {
      console.error(e2);
    }
  }
```

If you're interested in how to support Dark Mode with your website, read [this blogpost](https://csabaszabo.dev/blog/dark-mode-for-website-with-nuxtjs-and-vuetify).

Comment: I notice that we're using addListener again here, which is triggering a typescript deprecation warning.

Comment: @AnnKilzer Yep, that's because Safari doesn't yet support the new API so you are forced to use the (deprecated) `addListener` method if you want to support Safari.

Comment: Looks like safari supports `addEventListener('change', ...` as of version 14 (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/onchange). Current version is 15, so this was adopted ~November 12, 2020.

Answer (score 5):

If you just do as MDN writes it works cross browser (where it's supported):

```
const mql = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)');
mql.onchange = (e) => { 
  /* ... */
}
```

Should be supported above IE. E.g. all Edge + modern browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/onchange

Comment: `onchange` is only supported starting with Safari 14, so it doesn't seem to offer any benefit compared to `addEventListener`. I.e. if you want to support Safari 14+ you can use `addEventListener`, if you need to support Safari 13 or below you need to do a check like in @Szabó Csaba's answer

Comment: @Mattia all companies I've worked at only support last 2 major versions of browsers, e.g. iOs 14 and 15. Supporting more takes a lot of resources, especially with IE and older safari versions

Comment: Fair enough on which browsers you want to support - I'm  not arguing you need to support older browsers. I'm just pointing out that the OP asked when to use "addEventListener to replace addListener". `onChange` doesn't seem to give you any advantage relative to `addEventListener` since it also is iOS 14+, and thus doesn't answer the question. If you're on iOS 14+ use `addEventListener` (or `onChange if you prefer that style) otherwise you have to check.

Comment: I can't remember exactly now but it was either ie11, ios14 or android, samsung browser? addEventListener method did not work and only .onchange method that's why MDN and I used it.. so the benifit is that one worked crossbrowser and the other did NOT!

I haven't checked the status today

Answer (score 0):

Based On [Szabó Csaba](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60000747/13417667) Answer

```js
const darkMediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');

function onPrefersColorScheme(status: MediaQueryListEvent): void {
  // TODO
}

function tryChromeandFirefox() {
  darkMediaQuery.addEventListener('change', onPrefersColorScheme);
}

function trySafari() {
  darkMediaQuery.addListener(onPrefersColorScheme);
}

try {
  tryChromeandFirefox();
} catch {
  try {
    trySafari();
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-empty
  } catch {}
}
```

Also, single-line trying to invoke (not recommended):

```js
// add `async` to
async function tryChromeandFirefox();
async function trySafari();

tryChromeandFirefox().catch(() => trySafari());
```