# Find documentation for activeX object "Shell.Explorer.2"

Tags: activex

few days ago I've searched a way to print directly without the print-dialog in Internet Explorer and found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096862/print-directly-from-browser-without-print-popup-window).

In this solution the ActiveX object "Shell.Explorer.2" (CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2) is used.
Now I'm interested to find more information (better: documentation) for this control, but without success.

Somebody got an idea where to find that information?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This CLSID corresponds to Microsoft WebBrowser ActiveX control. Check these links:

[WebBrowser Control Overviews and Tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752041(v=vs.85).aspx)

[WebBrowser Customization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa770041%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[how to add an AxWebBrowser in vs2012 c#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18419434/1768303)

Search StackOverflow for "WebBrowser" and "printing" and you should find heaps of useful information related to your printing task.