# print div without display print preview window

Tags: c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

when I am using window print method it will go to the print preview window and dont want this print directly goes to the selected network

```
        $("#btnPrint").click(function () {                  
                window.print();                 
        });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to skip browser default print preview and print content directly to printer in jquery/javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27633386/how-to-skip-browser-default-print-preview-and-print-content-directly-to-printer)

Comment: For security reasons it is not possible to print from inside browser without user action for approving print (i.e. print preview). A lot of duplicates here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27633386/how-to-skip-browser-default-print-preview-and-print-content-directly-to-printer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881055/how-to-printing-without-print-preview-window http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391178/window-print-without-opening-the-print-window http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908/silent-printing-in-a-web-application