# how i can print a page or part of the page from web browser without print window using javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php

Actually I am developing an POS application for my own shop in web.

Now for that in billing section have features like select the products and print bill. only two steps.

but while click on print then its appearing print setup window.. which is very annoying.

think, if i am using that application in counter, customers are standing in a line. so i must to do the billing as fast as possible to make customer happy. now for this window takes time for each bill, and every time i am using same printer. so i don't think this is necessary for me.

and ultimately time === money.

so i need this technical help.. please help if you can

Comment: duplicate of duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096862/print-directly-from-browser-without-print-popup-window
Seems to be a popular topic...

Comment: @d.sergeiev: Good catches. The difference here, perhaps, is that since this is for the OP's own shop, they control the end-user environment, which could matter.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't automatically print the page without the browser's print dialog showing first, not without a browser extension. Think of the ramifications of a web page being able to print without you confirming it... :-)

Since this is for your own shop, if you're willing to spend a bit of time on it, you can probably build your own modified version of [Chromium](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code) or [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Source_Code) (or [Konqueror](http://www.konqueror.org/getthesource/) or...) and have it by-pass the print dialog. That sounds like a big deal, but I expect the code change is fairly simple once you get the build toolchain working.