# Print existing pdf file directly to client default printer

Tags: asp.net, pdf, code-behind

There is any chance to print from code behind without print preview? Now i'm using a javascript function to print a PDF from an iframe (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22695248/8284271) but i need to send my existing pdf file to the default printer of client without showing the print dialog.

Comment: No, there's not. If there was, what would stop a website from spamming your printer with ads? Futhermore, there's already a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096862/print-directly-from-browser-without-print-popup-window

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih imagine the horror. Visit a site and it starts printing a newletter and some coupons.

Comment: @VDWWD Imagine a wife or girlfriend, if she comes home and finds printed letters of nearby girls interested in you. Have fun explaining this! 