# Print directly from JS or Using HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing

I have this tiny code just to get things clear. I have a button to click on and it must trigger a printing event but without opening a print pop-up.

***Can I actually do something like:***

1.when a user clicks on this `btnPrint`, a printer just starts printing without any pop-up window

2.and not print the current page but a document sent through some URL?

Thanks in advance!

JS:

```
$('.btnPrint').on('click', function () {
  window.print();
});
```

Comment: `1.when a user clicks on this btnPrint, a printer just starts printing without any pop-up window` No, that's not possible. `2.and not print the current page but a document sent through some URL?` And neither is that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1124848/4248328

Answer (score 0):

kiosk-printing This is work with chrome and opera

added any of these shortcut to the desktop
Chrome
     "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk-printing https://YOURDOMAIN
Opera
    "C:\Program Files\Opera\launcher.exe --kiosk --kiosk-printing https://YOURDOMAIN

Comment: For greater readability please use watermarks for code scopes.