# How to print content of iframe without opening windows popup

Tags: jquery

In my app, I want to print a PDF file that resides in iframe. Here is my code ..

```
<iframe src="pdf/output.pdf" id="pdfFrame"></iframe>
```

And here is the script to print the pdf..

```
document.getElementById("pdfFrame").focus();
document.getElementById("pdfFrame").contentWindow.print();
```

The code above  works fine but It opens a windows popup before printing. But as per my requirement I want direct laser print without opening the popup.

Is there  any way to do this ???

Comment: No you can't, there's no way to invoke the printer without user intervention. I'd be pissed off if some website started printing stuff without even a chance for me to change settings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Juan Mendes. As per one post on stack overflow, we can do it using vb script .. please refer this url : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096862/print-directly-from-browser-without-print-popup-window

Comment: But VB script is new for me,can you please tell me, in above link... how can i use vb script to print a PDF which resides in an iframe ?

Comment: Another option is using Chrome kiosk printer mode

Answer (score 0):

The only way to bypass the print dialog is to tweak settings in IE and to write some VBScript.

See [Bypass Printdialog in IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036074/bypass-printdialog-in-ie9)

It only works in IE9, if you can change every client's ActiveX settings. Really should only be used in an intranet scenario where you control the clients.

```
<script language="VBScript">
    sub Print()
        OLECMDID_PRINT = 6
        OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2
        OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER = 1
        call WB.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER,1)
    End Sub
    document.write "<object id='WB' width='0' height='0' classid='CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2'></object>"
</script>

<object id="WebBrowser1" width="0" height="0" classid="CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2"> </object>
<a href="#" onclick="Print()">Click Here to Print</a>
```