# How can I target only Internet Explorer 11 with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-11

What's the least error-prone way to target just IE11 with JavaScript?

Note: This should really only be done for analytics or informing the user what browser they're using. For everything else, there's feature detection.

Comment: Searching for "IE11 user-agent" will give you blog posts and this article everybody saw : http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/07/02/internet-explorer-11-dont-call-me-ie/

Comment: @dystroy that blog post doesn't seem to have any detection code. Even hough it does have IE11's (current) UA, many people won't know how to test for it.

Comment: For reference, here's the same question about IE10: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-internet-explorer-10-for-certain-situations-like-internet-e

Comment: IE11 has several user-agent strings: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11-user-agent-string-ua-string-sniffing-compatibility-with-gecko-webkit.aspx

Comment: I'd love to know what the bug was in the first place. :)

Comment: Reopened - for some reason all votes to reopen this question in the past ended up aging away, and there were *lots* of these reopen votes. Needless to say, the people who left these scathing comments were part of the problem, choosing to complain rather than actually doing anything to try and get the question reopened. In future, if your question isn't getting reopened despite your best efforts to bring community attention to it, and you feel strongly about getting it reopened, feel free to flag it for moderator attention, explain your case, and we'll have a look.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The User-agent string for IE 11 is currently this one :

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv 11.0) like Gecko
```

Windows 10 example:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

Which means your can simply test, for versions 11.xx,

```
var isIE11 = /Trident.*rv[ :]*11\./.test(navigator.userAgent);
```

As [IE10 user agent was](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh920767%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)
```

it's probably also safe to bet on the fact that now `Trident/X` is supposed to be the real versionning.

Comment: trident refers to the version of MSHTML, rv is the IE version

Comment: I'm using IE virtually via modern.ie and in IE 11.0.9600.x, there's actually a colon, not a space, between rv and the version number: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; rv:11.0) like Gecko` Had to switch to this regex: `!!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv[ :]?11\./)`

Comment: On win 7, IE 11 it throws as false.

Comment: @TechJerk What's `navigator.userAgent` ?

Comment: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2;.NET CLR 2.0.50727;.NET CLR 3.5.30279;.NET CLR 3.0.30729;Media Center PC 6.0;.NET4.0.0c;.NET4.0E;Infopath.2;rv:11.0) like Gecko

Comment: I modified as per @KevinJurkowski comment and it worked! Thanks!

Comment: How would I check for "If IE11 and above"? Would this work?
`!!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv[ :]?[1-9]{2}\./)`
Regex is not my strong suit, but using this for compatibility reasons and want the code to execute inside my if statement if it's IE12, IE13, etc. as well.

Comment: NOTE: this will *not* work for IE11 for the desktop on 64-bit Windows 8.1 Update with compatibility view enabled. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: What means `!!` please?

Comment: @Steffi `!!` changes a `null` to `false`, and any array to `true`. But there's a cleaner solution, I'll edit.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `/Trident.*rv[ :]*11\./.test(navigator.userAgent)`?

Answer (score 28):

IE11 keeps "Trident" in it's UA string, but drops MSIE. A simple way to detect the browser is IE11 or above (IE12, IE13, etc) is:

```
var isAtLeastIE11 = !!(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/) && !navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/));
```

If you want *just* IE11 (and you don't want future versions of IE to match), do this:

```
var isIE11 = !!(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/) && navigator.userAgent.match(/rv[ :]11/));
```

Comment: the revision is separated by a colon so isn't that rv:11

Comment: Thanks. Looks like MS changed this. I've updated the regex.

Answer (score 4):

```
var isIE11 = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7.0; rv 11/);
```

Source: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/07/02/internet-explorer-11-dont-call-me-ie/

Comment: On win 7, IE 11 it throws as false.

Comment: That's false on IE 11 for me too

Comment: it might be due to the dot which in regexp has to be escaped.

Answer (score 3):

This will set `ie` to the version of IE, or 0 if none. It'll work for 1 through 11, but may not detect future versions if Microsoft drops the Trident engine.

```
var ie = 0;
try { ie = navigator.userAgent.match( /(MSIE |Trident.*rv[ :])([0-9]+)/ )[ 2 ]; }
catch(e){}
```

You may also be interested in my related, more detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907445/how-to-detect-ie11/30907476#30907476).

Comment: This is the best little script for me. It targets all IE versions. It doesn't target Edge which I didn't need anyway. :) Thanks @Beejor!

Answer (score 3):

I use the following pattern to target all IE browsers. You can short it down if you only need IE 11.

```js
 /msie|trident|edge/g.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase());
```

Good luck!

Fredrik

Answer (score 3):

Here's a script you can use to detect any browser:

```
<script>

  // Opera
  var isOpera = (!!window.opr && !!opr.addons) || !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;

  // Firefox 1.0+
  var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';

  // Safari 3.0+ "[object HTMLElementConstructor]" 
  var isSafari = /constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement) || (function (p) { return p.toString() === "[object SafariRemoteNotification]"; })(!window['safari'] || safari.pushNotification);

  // Internet Explorer 6-11
  var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;

  // Edge 20+
  var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;

  // Chrome 1+
  var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;

  // Blink engine detection
  var isBlink = (isChrome || isOpera) && !!window.CSS;

  if (isFirefox==true) {
    alert(isFirefox)
    $('.container-fluid').css({"overflow-y":"auto","height":"150%"});  
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
navigator.sayswho= (function(){
   var N= navigator.appName, ua= navigator.userAgent, tem;
   var M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie)\/?\s*(\.?\d+(\.\d+)*)/i);
   if(M && (tem= ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i))!= null) M[2]= tem[1];
   M= M? [M[1], M[2]]: [N, navigator.appVersion,'-?'];
   return M;
})();
```

Source from [Browser detection in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript)

Updated for **IE=11**

Use this

```
var isIE11 = navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7.0; rv 11.0/);
```

Read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx