# JQuery tablesorter pager plugin doesn't work properly with IE11 in Edge mode

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

If you are using the Tablesorter Jquery plugin with the pager add on the table will not display any of the data. The data is there but it is hidden.

I suspect the browser feature detection method of the plugin can't handle IE11.

Anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It seems that IE11 have a problem with his userAgent.
A turnaround is to change clearTableBody function (working in jquery.tablesorter-2.0.3.js) like this :

```
this.clearTableBody = function (table) {
    //if ($.browser.msie) {
        function empty() {
            while (this.firstChild) this.removeChild(this.firstChild);
        }
        empty.apply(table.tBodies[0]);
    //} else {
    //    table.tBodies[0].innerHTML = "";
    //}
};
```

Comment: Crushed the bug! +1 sir.

Comment: So why is it writing directly to innerHTML when the browser isn't IE? Is this faster than the while loop?

Answer (score 20):

This is in a way due to Internet Explorer 11 having a user agent string that doesn't include "MSIE", so jQuery doesn't identify it properly (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684099/jquery-fail-to-detect-ie-11)).

But really, the TableSorter <del>Pager</del> code doesn't need to know which browser is running the code. Change the function `clearTableBody` to leverage jQuery's cross-browser implementation instead:

```
this.clearTableBody = function(table) {
    $(table.tBodies[0]).empty();
};
```

I have tested this in IE8, IE9, IE11, Chrome 31 and Firefox 24.

(And just now, I found a GitHub repo with a fork of TableSorter that has possibly fixed this already: https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter)

Comment: Mottie's tablesorter has fixed this already with 
`$(table)[0].config.$tbodies.children().detach();` 
which is just a more verbose way of calling `.empty()` from what I can tell.

Answer (score 4):

We have the same problem.
I've submitted a ticket directly to Microsoft.

Wait... and see...

https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/806279/bug-when-sorting-with-a-jquery-plugin

Answer (score -1):

One simple soltion - change the line in jquery.tablesorter.js from
`if($.browser.msie)` to:

`if(/msie/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()) || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/7.0") > 0)` works for me.

`/msie/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())` detects IE version 10 or below.
`window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/7.0") > 0` detects IE 11.