# tablesorter JQuery plugin not sorting with IE 11 and display block

Tags: jquery, css, html-table, tablesorter

I am using table sorter (http://tablesorter.com/). Everything looks OK, except for IE 11. For some reason, I have to use `<tbody style="display:block">` and it seems that this giving me a problem, because as soon I delete `"display:block"` it works.

I am using version  TableSorter 2.17.7.

Comment: check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504252/jquery-tablesorter-pager-plugin-doesnt-work-properly-with-ie11-in-edge-mode

Comment: Well, thank you very much, but with the version 2.17 that is fixed. The thing is right now is working with IE 10, but not with IE 11. When I delete "display block" the table looks terrible(another story) but the sorting works.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a code sample of what is going on or perhaps remake what you have done on JFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that the problem was I was using the option  widthFixed: true, when I initialized the table sorter object.

`$("#myTable").tablesorter({
  widthFixed: true
});` 

Check this out using IE 11
http://jsfiddle.net/e2z31ehe/20/

When you try with IE 11, it does not work with these settings. Try to delete the option widthFixed : true and try again, it will work.

Comment: how come you answered yourself and mark it as correct? :P

Comment: Because it was working after I made the change (and now you will be able to save some time it if you have this same problem):

http://jsfiddle.net/cyg14ygs/3/
But just to be a good citizen, I put the answer as not tested/correct.