# Internet Explorer 11 detection

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I know IE 11 has different user agent string than all other IE

```
 Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv 11.0) like Gecko
```

I have tried to detect IE 11 with answer specified for this question'

[Jquery fail to detect IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684099/jquery-fail-to-detect-ie-11)

Thats `!!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/7\./)`

But I am getting error 
`Object not found and needs to be re-evaluated.`

Then I openede developer console in IE11 and tried to access some predefined javascript objects, I am still getting same error.

I have tried

`navigator.userAgent`

`window.navigator`

`console.log('test');`

Anyone have any idea about it ?

Comment: @Bobkhin I have mentioned above my issue. getting error `Object not found and needs to be re-evaluated.`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect IE 11 with javascript in Asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871760/how-to-detect-ie-11-with-javascript-in-asp-net)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect IE11?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907445/how-to-detect-ie11)

Answer (score 225, accepted):

**Edit 18 Nov 2016**

This code also work (*for those who prefer another solution , without using ActiveX*)

```
var isIE11 = !!window.MSInputMethodContext && !!document.documentMode;
  // true on IE11
  // false on Edge and other IEs/browsers.
```

**Original Answer**

In order to check Ie11  , you can use this :  ( tested)

(or run [this](http://jsbin.com/remuya/1/edit?html,css,js,output))

`!(window.ActiveXObject) && "ActiveXObject" in window`

I have all VMS of IE :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Notice : this wont work for IE11 :

as you can see here , it returns true :

[image]

So what can we do :

Apparently , they added the machine bit space  :

ie11 :

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
```

ie12 :

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; rv:11.0) like Gecko"
```

so we can do:

```
/x64|x32/ig.test(window.navigator.userAgent)
```

this will return true only for ie11.

Comment: Doesn't that also result in other IE's?

Comment: Could you please try it in developer console and let me know

Comment: @MiqdadAli Didn't you see my pics ?

Comment: Worked for me with Developer Console compatibility mode in IE11. Thanks, Namir!

Comment: Just wondering: in your screenshots you only show !(window.ActiveXObject) and not the "ActiveXObject in window" part.. so does the whole thing returns true in IE11?

Comment: @Jan. yes. only IE11 would return true for this whole condition. I just showed that <11 return false.

Comment: That may work as suggested. Just keep in mind that future IE12 may also return true.

Comment: No browser ive tried on windows or mac seems to allow the live 'javascript:!(window.ActiveXObject)' to be added to the url

Comment: @IanSteffy This is just to show the result(!) of the operation. You can open a HTML file and add script tag and run the command inside that script. [Here run this](http://jsbin.com/remuya/1/edit?html,css,js,output).

Comment: `x64` returns both Chrome and Edge

Comment: Why are you using 2 "!" in your first code? Is that used to force returning a boolean value?

Comment: Wait, there's an IE12? I thought IE11 was the last one and that we soon won't have to worry about that stupid browser anymore! ☹

Comment: There is no IE12!  Why is nobody apart from Michael Scheper questioning this response?  Does the poster, Royi Namir, mean IE11 or Edge rather than IE12??  Or is this supposed to be some hypothetical future version of IE?

Comment: Does **not** work for my IE 11.0.9600.19431 on Windows 7 Enterprise. There is no `window.MSInputMethodContext`.

Answer (score 118):

To detect MSIE (from version 6 to 11) quickly:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE')!==-1
|| navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Trident/') > -1){
   /* Microsoft Internet Explorer detected in. */
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second `indexOf()` be `> -1`?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why it's >0 and not >-1, but "Trident/" shows up much farther into the appVersion string anyways-

Comment: This answer does not detect IE 11 specifically which is what the OP asked

Comment: Why not both `>= 0` or `> -1` ? Should be the same outcome but more readable / straightforward.

Comment: Note that appVersion is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/appVersion

Answer (score 26):

I use the following function to detect version 9, 10 and 11 of IE:

```
function ieVersion() {
    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    if (ua.indexOf("Trident/7.0") > -1)
        return 11;
    else if (ua.indexOf("Trident/6.0") > -1)
        return 10;
    else if (ua.indexOf("Trident/5.0") > -1)
        return 9;
    else
        return 0;  // not IE9, 10 or 11
}
```

Answer (score 22):

All of the above answers ignore the fact that you mention you have no window or navigator :-)

> Then I openede developer console in IE11

and thats where it says

> Object not found and needs to be re-evaluated.

and navigator, window, console, none of them exist and need to be re-evaluated. I've had that in emulation. just close and open the console a few times.

Comment: goodness gracious THANK YOU for actually reading the question and answering the problem with re-evaluation.

Comment: Worked for me too. This is why there will be partying around the world when IE dies.

Comment: Closing and opening the console worked for me. Strange behavior compared to Firefox or Chrome (but it's IE, so that figures.)

Answer (score 17):

A pretty safe & concise way to detect **IE 11 only** is

```
if(window.msCrypto) {
    // I'm IE11 for sure
}
```

or something like this

```
var IE11= !!window.msCrypto;
```

`msCrypto` is a prefixed version of the `window.crypto` object and only implemented in IE 11.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/crypto

Comment: Thanks, I used the reverse: `if(window.crypto)` since `msCrypto` wasn't detected in `@types`

Answer (score 10):

Okay try this, simple and for IE11 and IE below 11 version

```
browserIsIE = navigator.userAgent.toUpperCase().indexOf("TRIDENT/") != -1 || navigator.userAgent.toUpperCase().indexOf("MSIE") != -1;
```

`navigator.userAgent.toUpperCase().indexOf("TRIDENT/") != -1` for IE 11 version
`navigator.userAgent.toUpperCase().indexOf("MSIE") != -1` for IE below 11 version

```js
browserIsIE = navigator.userAgent.toUpperCase().indexOf("TRIDENT/") != -1 || navigator.userAgent.toUpperCase().indexOf("MSIE") != -1;

console.log('Is IE Browser : '+ browserIsIE)
```

Answer (score 4):

And how I implemented this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  !(window.ActiveXObject) && "ActiveXObject"
  function isIE11(){
    return !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv[ :]*11\./);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I think you have a typo in your function. First, you do the condition check, which is not used. Second, perhaps you mean `&& "ActiveXObject" in window`. Third: what the trick with double negation `!!` ?

Comment: !! pretty much means 'Coerce to boolean'.

Answer (score 2):

[This link was helpful](https://codepen.io/gapcode/pen/vEJNZN) . It contains the javascript code to detect all versions of IE up to IE11.  I tested the script with IE11 emulator. To find the IE11 emulator, right-click on the web browser click "Inspect element". At the bottom-left of the page, scroll down the navigation bar and click the desktop icon. The "User Agent String" dropdown box contains options to emulate IE6-11.

It works. I just used it some minutes before writing this answer. Cannot post snapshots - not enough reputation.

---

This is the code - follow the link to view it again:

```js
// Get IE or Edge browser version
var version = detectIE();

if (version === false) {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<s>IE/Edge</s>';
} else if (version >= 12) {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Edge ' + version;
} else {
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'IE ' + version;
}

// add details to debug result
document.getElementById('details').innerHTML = window.navigator.userAgent;

/**
 * detect IE
 * returns version of IE or false, if browser is not Internet Explorer
 */
function detectIE() {
  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;

  // Test values; Uncomment to check result …

  // IE 10
  // ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)';

  // IE 11
  // ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko';

  // Edge 12 (Spartan)
  // ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.0';

  // Edge 13
  // ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586';

  var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
  if (msie > 0) {
    // IE 10 or older => return version number
    return parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf('.', msie)), 10);
  }

  var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
  if (trident > 0) {
    // IE 11 => return version number
    var rv = ua.indexOf('rv:');
    return parseInt(ua.substring(rv + 3, ua.indexOf('.', rv)), 10);
  }

  var edge = ua.indexOf('Edge/');
  if (edge > 0) {
    // Edge (IE 12+) => return version number
    return parseInt(ua.substring(edge + 5, ua.indexOf('.', edge)), 10);
  }

  // other browser
  return false;
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Mono|Fira+Sans:300);
body {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: "Fira Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3rem;
}

h1 {
  color: darkgrey;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 4rem;
}

p {
  color: darkgrey;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Fira Mono", monospace;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<h1>Detect IE/Edge version with JavaScript.<br> Updated to recognize Internet Explorer 12+ aka Edge.</h1>
<h2 id="result">detecting…</h2>
<p id="details">n/a</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using this RegExp seems works for IE 10 and IE 11:

```
function isIE(){
    return /Trident\/|MSIE/.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
}
```

I do not have a IE older than IE 10 to test this.

Answer (score 1):

For a minimal approach and untill IE officially dies on the August 17th 2021 ✌️ I'm using the IE conditional statement in reverse `<!--[if !IE]> --><!-- <![endif]-->`.

```html
<style>
:root{display:none!important}
</style>
<!--[if !IE]> -->
<style>
:root{display:initial!important}
</style>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Navigator:-

The `navigator` is an object that contains all information about the client machine's browser.

`navigator.appName` returns the name of the client machine's browser.

```js
navigator.appName === 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' ||  !!(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/) || navigator.userAgent.match(/rv:11/)) || (typeof $.browser !== "undefined" && $.browser.msie === 1) ? alert("Please dont use IE.") : alert("This is not IE")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: appName is Netscape on IE 11. They did everything they could to trick developers.

Answer (score 0):

I found IE11 is giving more than one user agent strings in different environments.

Instead of relying on `MSIE`, and other approaches, It's better to rely on `Trident` version

```
const isIE11 = userAgent => userAgent.match(/Trident\/([\d.]+)/) ? +userAgent.match(/Trident\/([\d.]+)/)[1] >= 7;
```

Hope this helps :)