# I want a text box to appear on my website if someone uses IE11

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a second post for my last one that got on hold.

I want a text box to appear when I or someone open my website in IE11 because I had some issues, the issues got sorted out. But I want this code for another time if something happens again.

In my [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51500455/i-want-a-text-box-appear-when-my-client-is-using-only-ie-11-to-open-my-website) a guy called Zani, gave a code that only reacted on IE11, but it is not working as it should. In my IE11 Console it says:

> SCRIPT5007 : Unable to get property 'style' of undefined or null reference.

It doesn't matter if I put it a JavaScript file or I script it into HTML.

The code is:

```
var isIE11 = !!window.MSInputMethodContext && !!document.documentMode;
if(isIE11)
  document.getElementById("IDOfYourElement").style.display="block";
```

I'm normally good in HTML and CSS, but Javascript is a whole different level. I'm not completely sure where there is something wrong. but I think it has something to do with `style`, and at the point where I should write the ID of my element, I have changed it to the correct ID and there is no wrong grammar there.

EDIT: 1
Here is the code of the site.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
</script>
<link href="/CSS/Incompatible.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Incompatible.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var isIE11 = !!window.MSInputMethodContext && !!document.documentMode;
    if(isIE11)
  document.getElementById("simpleModal").style.display="block";
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="modalBtn" class="button" onClick="myModal()">Click
Here</button>
<div id="simpleModal" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="closeBtn" onClick="myModalHide()">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Hello...I am a modal</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nulla repellendus nisi, sunt consectetur ipsa velit repudiandae aperiam modi quisquam nihil nam asperiores doloremque mollitia dolor deleniti quibusdam nemo commodi ab.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Okay so by putting it on the bottom of the HTML page works. But I really want Javascript to be in a javascript file. so I tried making a ready function, but it don't work.

Comment: perhaps the id `"IDOfYourElement"` doesn't exist - perhaps Zani didn't know the ID, and left it to you, the author of that HTML (which you are good at) to replace `IDOfYourElement` with *the ID of **your** element*

Comment: I changed "IDOfYourElement" to simpleModal. Which i have in my code.

Comment: that ID does not exist in the HTML you posted in the other question????

Comment: I now added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the error is saying is that there is no element with ID `IDOfYourElement` (or whatever ID you placed here). So one of 2 things:

1. You don't have an element with the ID (`IDOfYourElement`) OR
2. The javascript file is loading before the elements have loaded.

If the case is number 2, then you should make sure that your `<script>` tag is included at the very bottom of your HTML file, Or wrap your javascript code with a ready function.

**EDIT**

To wrap your code in a ready function you can achieve that using Jquery or pure Javascript. Here are the examples

**Using Pure Javascript**

```
window.onload = function() {
  // DOM has loaded, you can execute your JS code now.
}
```

**Using Jquery**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // DOM has loaded, you can execute your JS code now.
});
```

Comment: It was the case number 2 I added it to the bottom and it worked. If I want the code in the Javascript file. how do I make that ready function?

Comment: @JessenJonas I updated my answer to show you how to wait for the page to load before executing your JS.

Comment: Thank you! That really helped!