# Get rid of FormData.entries() in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, form-data

I need to get rid or skip `FormData.entries()` in IE11. I have the code to check for IE 11 from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22242528/1824579

```
        var formData = new FormData();

        ...

        if (!navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Trident/') > -1) { //is 29 in IE; -1 in Chrome
            for (var pair of formData.entries()) { //error in IE11
                ...
            }
        }
```

So all I want to achieve is, that if the Browser is IE11 it should skip this section. By now I am not able to achieve this. In the console i only get this error shown up:
`SCRIPT1004: Expected ';' Index(1094, 31)` which is exactly after the word `pair` in this line: `for (var pair of formData.entries()) {`

I don't know why IE11 is coming so far, because a log or the result of `navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Trident/')` is `29` in IE11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Browser_compatibility) is not supported in IE11. This is a syntax-level issue that can't be solved by feature detection. Your best bet is to transpile your source code with something like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/), targeting IE11.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be with using the logical NOT operator. Checking "indexOf > -1" should do the trick or you may need to use an extra set of brackets:

```
if (!(navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Trident/') > -1))
```