# i'm creating special stylesheet for IE 10 and 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

can i use this simple script to detect IE 10 and 11

```js
if($.browser.version == 11.0 || $.browser.version == 10.0) {

  $("body").addClass("ie");
  
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Internet Explorer 11 detection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21825157/internet-explorer-11-detection)

Comment: I'm glad you are. Is this a question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684099/jquery-fail-to-detect-ie-11

Comment: [`$.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) is removed since jQuery_1.9.

Comment: jQuery.browser
Contains flags for the useragent, read from navigator.userAgent. This property was removed in jQuery 1.9 and is available only through the jQuery.migrate plugin. Please try to use feature detection instead.

Comment: Curious why you even need this. In older versions like IE6,7,8 was understandable but not for neweer versions

Comment: but i am using that migrated plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this

```
function getInternetExplorerVersion()
{
  var rv = -1;
  if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
  {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    var re  = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
    if (re.exec(ua) != null)
      rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
  }
  else if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape')
  {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    var re  = new RegExp("Trident/.*rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
    if (re.exec(ua) != null)
      rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
  }
  return rv;
}
getInternetExplorerVersion();
```

Comment: Has this been tested for IE 10 & 11? Also, this won't detect MS Edge. - TBH, this just shouldn't be encouraged anyway.

Comment: IE 10 has MSIE and Edge has Trident..check in ur browser

Comment: still makes no sense to need to do this and goes against best practices