# How can I target IE9 and above with javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser-detection

I know that IE11 changed the way `navigator.userAgent` is sent, and I've seen [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447373/how-can-i-target-only-internet-explorer-11-with-javascript). This works well if all we need is IE11 and above, but we need IE9 and above. I had read somewhere that the Trident code name was introduced in IE9, but a quick test of IE8 shows that the user agent there also contains Trident.

My regex is not very good; how can I split out these strings to determine what's between `Trident/` and the following semicolon so I can tell which version I'm dealing with? (Please don't tell me to use feature detection instead; that's not an option here.)

IE 8:

```
"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; BO1IE8_v1;ENUS)"
```

IE 9:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)"
```

My existing code (which doesn't catch IE8) looks like this:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/)) {
   // it's supported; do stuff
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to get the 5.0 from IE9 and the 4.0 from IE8.

Comment: In this case, you would have to retrieve a substring of the user agent string.  Why not just use the conditional HTML tags though?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that user agent strings to catch certain versions of browsers are not that reliable.  The user agent strings can be spoofed easily.

Comment: This is integrated into a CMS, which precludes us from adding things like that.

Comment: Which CMS are you using?

Comment: A customized version of Expression Engine.

Comment: I've used conditional tags in EE a few times, so I am not sure why this isn't feasible here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My regex is not very good; how can I split out these strings to determine what's between Trident/ and the following semicolon so I can tell which version I'm dealing with?

You want to use a capture group and get the second element of the array, which will give you the captured portion.

```
var stringAfterTrident = navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident([^;]+);/)[1];
//should return ["Trident/5.0;", "/5.0"] and you want the second item of the array
```

`/Trident([^;]+);/` basically says starts with Trident, capture one or more character that is not the semicolon until there is a semicolon.