# Restrict page access to IE > 9

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I'm building an intranet site (MVC4) which should be accessible only with IE. We are using a Citrix environment and need [HDX Mediastream Redirection](https://supportforums.cisco.com/docs/DOC-29189) which currently works only for IE.

Right now I'm using the following

```
        if (!Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("ie") && !Request.Browser.Browser.ToLower().Contains("internetexplorer"))
        {
            return View("badBrowser");
        }
```

which does not work for IE 11, e.g. Now I could add

```
!!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv 11\./)
```

to include IE 11 as discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447373/how-can-i-target-only-internet-explorer-11-with-javascript) thread. But .. **is there a better way than comparing proprietary user-agent strings that are likely to change in the future?**

Comment: I'm not quite sure of what "HDX Mediastream Redirection" is but maybe it's possible to detect the presence of this feature in a particular browser using something like modernizr, instead of targeting specific browsers. Just my 2c.

Comment: If at all possible, test for the existence of HDX MediaStream Redirection (is there a JS API? Does it send a server header?) rather than checking the user agent string. Checking the UA string should always be a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft changes the useragent from time to time

In ie 11 the user agent is --> see here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

to dectect ie more effectly:-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

hope this help.