# Detect if any kind of IE (MSIE)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, internet-explorer

I dont want to allow users to access my site with Microsoft Internetexplorer (ANY VERSION).

What I´ve found so far was to detect if it´s lower or equal version 10.

A very annoing thing: Internetexplorer >v10 doesn´t admit to be a InternetExplorer.

What i´ve found and tried so far:

```
if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE")!=-1){
alert("You use IE. That´s no good.");
}
```

or

```
if ( $.browser.msie ) {
alert( $.browser.version );
}
```

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I would use any solution if it is in javascript, jquery or php if there is one.

Comment: Why you wanna do that?

Comment: Because he doesn´t want to support IE users maybe?

Comment: excellent question! +1.. what else can i do to help drive people away from ie?

Comment: here you can find a proper example http://stackoverflow.com/a/10965091/2481383

Comment: For IE 11 check for `Trident/7.0; rv:11.0` in user_agent

Comment: Didnt this `if($.browser.msie)`  work?

Comment: Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447373/how-can-i-target-only-internet-explorer-11-with-javascript

Comment: There is a difference between not wanting to support and actively blocking. It's an interesting question from an educational point of view, but why would you want to do this in production code, except when you're a Mozilla employee and want to prove that IE is bad.

Comment: @GolezTrol Supporting IE in any kind isn´t fun...maybe just an "tip" in the corner that you shouldn´t use IE for a better user expirience

Comment: For IE6 or even 8 or 9, it's a different story, because they are outdated, but IE11 is a modern browser like the others. Taking small differences between browsers into account should be a part of your job as a web developer. Unnecessarily confusing and scaring your users isn't really part of a 'better user experience'.

Comment: I *do not believe this is a duplicate* +1 :)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. This is a legit question. Perfect for use on an intranet etc.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

This works for me to detect any Version of the IE 5-11 (Internet Explorer) **(Aug/05/2014)**:

```
if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' ||  !!(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/) || navigator.userAgent.match(/rv:11/)) || (typeof $.browser !== "undefined" && $.browser.msie == 1))
{
  alert("Please dont use IE.");
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, as of August 2015, this is not working for me.  Interestingly (annoyingly), navigator.appName is set to Netscape instead of Microsoft Internet Explorer.

Comment: It'd be nice to also check for the version of IE.

Comment: ```navigator.userAgent.match(/rv:11/)``` you must fix this one because it contains no ``:`` marks in your regex string

Comment: @JefferyThaGintoki fixed it, thank you.

Comment: I confirm that latest versions of IE (not Edge) give "Netscape" as navigator.appName.

Comment: @ohio818, it's assuming malware-like behavior now lol

Comment: best alert message ever. !! made my life miserable since 3 days

Comment: As of 2020 I also see 'Netscape' instead of IE in navigator.appName

Answer (score 29):

This is because each release of Internet Explorer updates the [user-agent string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

`MSIE` tokens have been removed in Internet Explorer 11 and `$.browser` uses `navigator.userAgent` to determine the platform and it is removed in jQuery 1.9.

You can use following code to determine the browser with pure java-script.

```
var isIE = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/g) || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/g);

if(isIE){
 alert("IE"); 
}
else{
 alert("Not IE");   
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: That´s what he allready wrote in his question....doesn´t work for >10

Comment: Yes, sorry, I have updated the answer.

Comment: Why does the code use double-negation? (`!!`)

Comment: @rinogo I wondered this myself, having never seen that pattern before. Discovered it's to make the values a boolean as .match() returns an array of results and without them isIE would just be ["Trident"] or ["MSIE"].


One could also write this:
`var isIE = /Trident/.test(navigator.userAgent) || /MSIE/.test(navigator.userAgent);`

Comment: `const isIE = /Trident|MSIE/.test(navigator.userAgent);` is the shorter equivalent

Answer (score 7):

if you are not interessted wich version of ie the user currently use you can try get it work with detecting if the browser supports the `Conditional Compilation Statements`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kx09ct1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

```
if(/*@cc_on!@*/false)
{
    // You use IE. That´s no good.
    alert("oh my god");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [conditional compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/8ka90k2e(v=vs.94).aspx)
, e.g.

```
<script>
var isIE = false;
/*@cc_on isIE = true; @*/
</script>
```

But note that IE11 doesn't observe this in Standards Mode. User Agent sniffing is generally a bad idea, but as IE becomes more standards-compliant, it also becomes harder to detect (hopefully also meaning less need to)

Answer (score 1):

For IE> 10 which is currently IE 11, user-agent carries something in Browser's HTTP request headers

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; **rv:11.0**) like Gecko

You can put a check on "**rv:11.0**" for version 11.  Let me know if you need code for this.

Answer (score 1):

I've found (maybe in SO) in the past this script and it worked for me (IE 10 too)

```
<![if IE]>
<script type='text/javascript'>
if(/*@cc_on!@*/false)
var bIsIE = 1;
</script>
<![endif]>
```

and then

```
if (typeof (bIsIE) != 'undefined')
{
    //IE :(
}
else
{
    //NOT IE :)
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me with IE11 with or without compatibility mode