# If IE tag not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML

```
  <script>
    internet_explorer = false;
  </script>
  <!--[if IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      internet_explorer = true;
    </script>
  <![endif]-->
```

and this JS:

```
console.log(internet_explorer)
```

When I run this on all browsers it should be false and it is. However, it is supposed to be true on Internet Explorer but it's false. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional comments are no longer supported

Support for conditional comments has been removed in Internet Explorer 10 standards and quirks modes for improved interoperability and compliance with HTML5.

Source:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Is there any suggested alternative?

Comment: To add that there is a property called `document.documentMode` that is IE-specific, but it's not there for Edge.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24861073/detect-if-any-kind-of-ie-msie might be able to help you, as Jon Snow commented I am not sure if it will help you for Edge